# How to calculate the number of recursive calls made to the Ackerman() function in C

Tags: c, recursion, global, counter, ackermann

I tried writing this code to calculate the Ackerman value and also the number of times the function is called. However, the counter is stuck at 0 all the time. Could you help me out?

```
/*
A(m,n) =    n+1, if m==0
A(m,n) =    A(m-1,1), if m>0 and n==0
A(m,n) =    A(m-1,A(m,n-1)), if m>0 and n>0
*/
#include<stdio.h>
static int w=0;
int ackerman(int m,int n)
{

    w=w+1;
    if(m==0)
        return n+1;
    else if(m>0 && n==0)
        return ackerman(m-1,1);
    else if(m>0 && n>0)
        return ackerman(m-1,ackerman(m,n-1));
}
int mainackerman()
{
    int m,n;
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    printf("%d %d",ackerman(m,n),w);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a sequence-point issue.  On the same line as you are calling `ackerman`, you are using a value that is affected by that call.  This is undefined behaviour.  Do this instead:

```
int result = ackerman(m,n);
printf("%d %d", result, w);
```

There is a [good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/1553090) with some excellent answers related to sequence-points.  It's related to C++, but the idea is essentially the same as for C.